# How to use Bootstrap in non-responsive websites

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been using the instructions on this site:

http://coderpills.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-responsive-site/

...in order to make Bootstrap stop behaving responsively, but one thing still is not working. When the window becomes really narrow, the text-size still gets blown up.

How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this  [Link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

A simple example is

```
<h1 class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"> Some text here </h1>
```

The above text will show in large device like on desktop, laptop and larger devices.

```
<h3 class="visible-xs"> Some text here</h3>
```

When the browser become narrower like in the size of smartphone's or smaller then that then the above heading will show and the first one will hide automaticly...